# How to find the speed that minimizes the total cost of a trip?

Tags: calculus, optimization

Here are some facts about semi-trucks and a trip between Chicago and New Orleans.

(a) The trip is 750 miles.

(b) Running at 50 mph, the truck gets around 4 miles per gallon.

(c) For each mph increase in speed, the truck losses 1/10 of a mile per gallon in mileage.

(d) The driver team gets \$27 per hour.

(e) Keeping the truck on the road costs 15 dollars per hour over and above the cost of fuel.

(f) Diesel fuel costs \$3.90 per gallon.

- Write a function, C(x), for the total cost of driving the truck from Chicago to New Orleans in terms of the **constant** speed x.
- At what (constant) speed should the truck be driven to minimize the cost of the trip? Use calculus to minimize costs.

#### Progress

I know that the constraint is $xh=750$ and I know that it something$+27h+(15h/3.90)$ but I don't know how to use the mpg to my equation...

Answer (score 1):

The total cost should be:
(cost for driver team) + (cost of fuel) + (cost to keep the truck on the road)
The cost of the driver team is 27h, as you have written. The cost to keep the truck on the road is 15h. The "over and above the cost of fuel" doesn't mean that you should divide this by the cost of fuel per gallon, it means "in addition to fuel cost". So you need to figure out the cost of fuel, which is where you will use the mpg.

Comment: So C(x)=Cost of fuel+27h+15h??

I'm just having trouble finding the cost of fuel itself...I don't know how to manipulate the numbers correctly.

Comment: The cost of fuel should be (gallons used)*(cost per gallon) = (gallons used)*3.90. The number of gallons used is (total distance in miles)/(miles/gallon). You can use the given information to write an expression for miles/gallon in terms of x.

Comment: C(x)=-292.5x+(31500/x)+26325

Comment: Cprime(x)=-292.5-(31500/x^2))=0
there is no value for x?

Comment: Is there no answer? Cprime is if undefined at 0 and x=sqrt(-1400/13) when solving for Cprime=0...The truck can't move zero miles an hour and the truck can't go over 90mph because that is 0mpg...So none of the critical points fit within the interval?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you seem to be experiencing is that you are unsure on your costs, but also not putting together an equation to minimise the fuel consumption per mile.

There are two points of attack for this one. The cost per hour (which is set), and the miles per gallon / miles per hour. They are separate and attached at the same time. The miles per hour and miles per gallon cost is intrinsically tied to the the trip distance, and also the best cost point for speed. You need to start writing down every value you can see, then interpret the mathematical words (such as miles per gallon{miles/gallon}). Remember, you can use measurements in reverse too... (miles / gallons can also be used other ways..) I hope that gives you a few hints?